# misinterpreting logic expression

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Represent in first order logic

"Every person who dislikes all vegetarians is smart"

### My solution

$\forall x,y$ $person(x) \land vegetarian(y) \land dislike(x,y) \rightarrow smart(x) $

People say to me that this is not correct. I don't understand why?

Where is my misconception?

Comment: Note that, one problem among many here (and as the answers all reveal): you need to be careful to use parentheses to enclose expressions. E.g., you need to use parentheses to make explicit the scope of a quantifier, to make explicit what is implying what, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sort of translation can be done easily if you take it in stages. Consider

> (a) Every person who dislikes all vegetarians is smart
>
> (b) $\forall x$( *person-who-dislikes-all-vegetarians* $(x) \to smart(x))$
>
> (c) $\forall x([person(x) \land \forall y\{(vegetarian(y) \to dislike(x, y)\}] \to smart(x))$

The move from (a) to (b) needs no explanation, and the move from (b) to (c) just involves noting that *person-who-dislikes-all-vegetarians* $(x)$ says that $x$ is a person and for any vegetarian $y$, $x$ dislikes $y$. OK?

Now, that's fine and you can stop there. But suppose you wanted to bring the quantifers all to the front. Then (c) is equivalent to

> (d) $\forall x(\forall y[person(x) \land \{(vegetarian(y) \to dislike(x, y)\}] \to smart(x))$

(Do you see why?) But now (d) is $\forall x$ followed by something of the form $(\forall yFxy \to Gx)$.

But now the crucial observation. $(\forall yFxy \to Gx)$ is equivalent to  $(\neg\forall yFxy \lor Gx)$, which is equivalent to $(\exists y\neg Fxy \lor Gx)$ which is equivalent to $\exists y(\neg Fxy \lor Gx)$ which is equivalent to $\exists y(Fxy \to Gx)$. In short, dragging a quantifier out from the antecedent of a conditional flips it into the dual quantifier. That means (d) is equivalent to

> (e) $\forall x\exists y([person(x) \land \{(vegetarian(y) \to dislike(x, y)\}] \to smart(x))$.

I hope that, along with Henning's answer, shows *why* your original answer was mistaken!

Comment: +1Nicely explained!, especially the explicit "logic" behind how "dragging a quantifier out from an antecedent of a conditional flips it into the dual quantifier." (And nicely disambiguated, e.g., using parentheses to enclose the antecedent.)

Comment: Your answer and that of henning was really really useful. I would both upvote you if I could. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Your solution claims that whenever there is someone who dislikes *some* vegetarian, the one doing the disliking is smart.

For example, suppose that indeed, everyone who dislikes all vegetarians is smart.
Suppose further John is kinda stupid, and likes everybody *except* for Brian, who is a vegetarian. That is not a conflict, because John doesn't dislike *all* vegetarians: Henry is a vegetarian, and John likes him just fine. However your first-order formula is *false* in this situation.

It is false because the only thing that is needed to make a $\forall$ formula false is a single counterexample. And $x=\text{John}, y=\text{Brian}$ is a counterexample -- the body of the quantifier then becomes:
$$ \text{person(John)}\land\text{vegetarian(Brian)}\land\text{dislike(John,Brian)}\to\text{smart(John)}$$
and here all the conjuncts to the left of the $\to$ are true, but the conclusion on the right is not.

I suspect you started out fine with something like
$$ \forall x\big[\text{person}(x)\land\text{dislikes-all-vegetarians}(x)\to\text{smart}(x)\big]$$
but then you when wrong translating "dislikes-all-vegetarians". By itself it is
$$ \text{dislikes-all-vegetarians}(x) \equiv
\forall y[\text{vegetarian}(y)\to \text{dislike}(x,y)]$$
and we can insert it into the first formula to get
$$ \forall x\big[\text{person}(x)\land\forall y[\text{vegetarian}(y)\to \text{dislike}(x,y)]\to\text{smart}(x)\big]$$
Note that here you *cannot* move the $\forall y$ out such that it is neighbor to the $\forall x$, because it is important for the meaning that $\forall y$ is *subordinate to* the $\rightarrow$ rather than the opposite.

---

We can insist on getting a logically equivalent formula where all quantifiers are out at the front (a "prenex formula"), but then the $\forall y$ becomes $\exists y$, which makes the result rather unrecognizable as a rendering of the original English sentence:
$$ \forall x \exists y \big[ \text{person}(x) \land [\text{vegetarian}(y) \to \text{dislike}(x,y)] \to \text{smart}(x)]\big]$$
or
$$ \forall x \exists y \big[ \text{person}(x) \to \text{smart}(x) \lor [\text{vegetarian}(y) \land \neg\text{dislike}(x,y)]\big]$$
(more or less "every person is smart unless (possibly) if there is a vegetarian he doesn't dislike").

Answer (score 0):

$\forall x[ person(x) \rightarrow [\forall y[veg(y) \rightarrow dislike(x,y)]\rightarrow smart(x)]] $

Comment: I am not sure if the statement you wrote is equivalent to mine. I will check

Comment: Your statement is correct i think. And I can see why. But i cannot "intuitively" see why my solution is not correct

Comment: Is this your statement $\forall x,y$[ $person(x) \land vegetarian(y) \land dislike(x,y) \rightarrow smart(x)] $?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: They are not equivalent.

Comment: The other answer explains your mistake well